# Microsoft .NET Core 3 & Visual Studio - Linq Add Migration fails to createapphost after moving source code to new path / folder / directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, .net-core

I moved from this path:

C:\Users\chris\Dropbox\repos

To this:

C:\Users\chris\source\repos

Now, when I run an (`add migration`),It fails with an error finding the source code.

Comment: Sometimes you need to select the project in the default project dropdown just above the package manager console. Also a nice restart of VS doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that paths are hard-coded in the file:
Project-Folder\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\project-name.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
I updated the paths in the file with the new path and now the add-migration command works again!